Simulation of Markov processes with exponential timestepping
Let $(Y_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a time-homogeneous Markov process with transition semigroup $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$. Numerical simulation of $(Y_t)_{t\ge0}$ can be done in the following way:

Choose an initial state $Y_0$
Let $i:=1$ and $\tau_0:=0$
Choose $\tau_i$
Draw $Y_{t_i}$ from $\kappa_{t_i}(Y_{\tau_{i-1}},\;\cdot\;)$
Goto 3

This way we can obtain a skeleton $(Y_{\sigma_0},\ldots,Y_{\sigma_n})$, where $\sigma_k:=\sum_{i=1}^k\tau_i$, of a path $Y(\omega)$ of $Y$.
Traditionally, we simply choose a fixed step size $\tau_i=.01$ or something like that. Now, what I wonder is, what happens if we let $\tau_i$ be an exponentially distributed random variable, with parameter $\alpha_i>0$, instead. We clearly assume that all $\tau_i$ are independent.
My question is: Would this sampling procedure change the distribution; i.e. would we still obtain a skeleton of a path $Y(\omega)$ of $Y$? Or did we affect the distribution of the samples by the additional randomness?
Maybe I'm thinking too complicated, but I think this procedure would mean that we effectively "restart" $Y$ at the times $\tau_i$. That is, formally we would have constructed a process $$X_t:=Y^{(n)}_{t-\sigma_{n-1}}\;\;\;\text{for }t\in[\sigma_{n-1},\sigma_n)\tag1,$$ where all $(Y^{(n)})_{t\ge0}$ are independent (and independent of all the $\tau_i$) with $Y^{(n)}\sim Y$ and $$Y^{(n)}_0\sim\mu\left(Y^{(n-1)}_{\tau_{n-1}-},\;\cdot\;\right)\tag2$$ for some Markov kernel $\mu$. (e.g. $\mu$ being a Dirac at the previous state).
After some research, I've found that this construction is considered in this paper, but only for the case where all $\alpha_i$ are equal and $\mu$ is simply a measure. An expression for the transition semigroup $(\tilde\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ of $X$ is given and it is actually different from $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$. In fact, they've showed that $$(\tilde\kappa_tf)(x)=e^{-\alpha_1t}(\kappa_tf)(x)+\alpha_1\int\mu({\rm d}y)\int_0^te^{-\alpha_1s}(\kappa_sf)(y)\;{\rm d}s.$$
What I now wonder is what happens if we assume that all $\alpha_i$ are not only distinct, but even build a strictly increasing sequence. Intuitively, I think the second term should vanish.
In any case, I'm not 100% sure if this is the right approach. What I actually want really is that $X$ follows the same transition semigroup as $Y$ does. Is there any research on this? Or am I thinking way too complicated and the scheme above works just fine even with random (exponentially distributed) $\tau_i$'s?
